# Implement hierarchal sampaling active learning

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I recently came across this paper proposing [hierarchical sampling for active learning](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~djhsu/papers/hier.pdf). The algorithm (pseudocode) is as follows:

```
[pseudocode][2]
```

I am working to implement this using Python 3 and to begin I wrote the following code:

```
Z = ward(X.todense())
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
dn = dendrogram(Z)
```

which hierarchically clusters the dataset. However, I am now unsure how to access the classes to whcih each row belongs to. How can I do this?

Comment: how far did you get with this? i'm also trying to implement this!